# Outer SemiContinuity of the Intersection Set

Tags: analysis

Let $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a locally bounded function.

Consider the following set-valued map $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightrightarrows \mathbb{R}^m$ (i.e. $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is mapped to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$) defined as:
$$ \Phi(x) := \bigcap_{\rho > 0} \overline{ \phi(x + \rho \mathbb{B}) } $$

Prove that $\Phi(\cdot)$ is outer semicontinuous, i.e.:

for any sequence $\{(f_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, $(f_i,y_i) \in \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and $(f_i,y_i) \rightarrow (f,y)$,  such that $f_i \in \Phi(y_i)$, we have $f \in \Phi(y)$.

Notes: $\overline{S}$ denotes the closure of the set $S$. Therefore $\overline{ \phi(x + \rho \mathbb{B}) }$ denotes the closure of the set $\{\phi(x+\epsilon): \ \epsilon \in \delta \mathbb{B}\}$, where $\mathbb{B} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is the unitary closed ball.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a little suspicious, since I haven't use local boundedness anywhere. I'll post this anyway; since I was not able to find a mistake.
(In case you know an example showing that the above is not true without the assumption that $\phi$ is locally bounded, please, let me know. Including the example would be nice.)
$\newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}\newcommand{\ve}\varepsilon\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\|{#1}\|}\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}$

---

First, let's have a look at the meaning of your function $\Phi(x)$. I will denote the ball of radius $\ve$ around $x$ by $B(x,\ve)$. I.e., $B(x,\ve)=x+\ve\mathbb B$.
$$y\in\Phi(x)=\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} \ol{\phi(B(x,\ve))}$$ 
means that, for each $\ve>0$, the point $y$ belongs to $\ol{\phi(B(x,\ve))}$, i.e. every neighborhood of $y$ intersects $\phi(B(x,\ve))$.
$$(\forall \delta>0)(\forall \ve>0) \phi(B(x,\ve))\cap B(y,\delta)\ne\emptyset$$
$$(\forall \delta>0)(\forall \ve>0) (\exists z) \norm{z-x}<\ve \land \norm{\phi(z)-y}<\ve$$

---

We know that $f_i\in\Phi(y_i)$, $y_i\to y$, $f_i\to f$.

Suppose we are given $\delta,\ve>0$.

First we choose $i$ such that $\norm{y_i-y}<\ve/2$ and $\norm{f_i-f}<\delta/2$.

We know that there exists $z$ such that $\norm{z-y_i}<\ve/2$ and $\norm{\phi(z)-f_i}<\delta/2$.

Using triangle inequality we get $\norm{z-y}<\ve$ and $\norm{\phi(z)-f}<\delta$. So for $y$ and $f$ (and any given positive $\delta$ and $\ve$) we have found $z$ that verifies the above condition.

---

Note: You multifunction $\Phi(x)$ can be equivalently defined as the intersection $\bigcap \ol{\phi(U)}$ over all neighborhoods $U$ of $x$.
As I've learned recently from Dave L. Renfro's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131738/cluster-point-of-a-function-at-a-point/132607#132607), this means that $\Phi(x)$ is the *cluster set* of the function $\phi$ at the point $x$. The references in this answer suggest that cluster sets have been studied quite extensively, so it is quite probable that *cluster multifunction* have been studied too and you'll be able to find some facts about it in the literature.

---

Added: Your question (at least if my reinterpretation of it is correct) in fact asks whether the multifunction assigning to each point cluster set  of a given function at this point has closed graph. I've tried to Google a little to see whether I found some known results on this function. What I was able to find was this:

- Andrej Jankech: [The construction and some properties of cluster multifunction](http://www.sav.sk/journals/uploads/0728135919JANKE.ps);
  Tatra Mountains Mathematical Publications. Volume 34, 2006, No. 2: 71-76.

This paper studies cluster function of $f$ defined as $C_f(x)=\bigcap_{U\in\mc N(x)} \overline{f(U)}$. By $\mc N(x)$ I mean the set of all neighborhoods of $x$. However, it does not mention the property that this multifunction has closed graph.

- Christian Richter: The Cluster Function of Single-Valued Functions; Set-Valued Analysis, Volume 14, Number 1 (2006), 25-40, DOI: [10.1007/s11228-005-5135-y](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11228-005-5135-y)

In this paper it is mentioned that a multifunction $F$ is the cluster function of some $f$ if $F$ has a closed graph and admits a selection $f$ whose graph is dense in the graph of $F$.

- Milan Matejdes: [Continuity properties of cluster multifunctions and closed graph theorems](http://www.sav.sk/journals/uploads/0219110117.pdf); Tatra Mt. Math. Publ. 40 (2008), 81–89.

This paper studies a more general notion of $\mathcal E$-cluster points. It is shown that the cluster multifunction $\mathcal E_F$ has closed graph.

Maybe these papers and the references given there can be useful for you if you plan to study the multifunction $\Phi$ further.

Comment: I'm not clear about the equivalence between $y \in \Phi(x)$ and the two conditions you provided. For instance, $B(x,\epsilon)$ is a neighborhood of $x$, I don't see why you address neighborhoods of $y$. Instead, I would say that "$\phi(x)$ + its limit points" contain $y$.

Comment: $B(x,\varepsilon)$ is the same thing as $x+\varepsilon\mathbb B$.

Comment: Yes, so I don't see why every neighborhood of $y$ intersects $\phi(B(x,\epsilon))$

Comment: $y$ belongs to [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28topology%29) of a set $A$ if an only if every neighborhood of $y$ intersects $A$. See also [limit point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_points) at Wikipedia.

Comment: We know that $f_i \in \bigcap_{\rho > 0} \overline{ \phi(y_i + \rho \mathbb{B}) } $. Taking the limit we have: $f = \lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} f_i \in \lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} \bigcap_{\rho > 0} \overline{ \phi(y_i + \rho \mathbb{B}) }$. Does such RHS contain (or is equal to) $\Phi(x)$?

Comment: @Adam: Maybe it would be reasonable to take this to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3160/outer-semicontinuity-of-the-intersection-set) instead of clustering the comments here.

Comment: Dear Martin, I'm not clear why "$y$ belongs to each $\overline{ \phi(B(x,\epsilon))}$". Intuitively, why this should be true if $\epsilon$ is "very large"? For instance, if $\phi(\cdot)$ is continuous, then $\Phi(x) = \phi(x)$ is single-valued and $y \notin \phi(x+\epsilon)$.