# Prove $A=\{ x \in \mathbb R \mid \exists \{ x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty \subset (0,1] \ s.t. \ \lim x_n=0, \lim f(x_n)=x \}$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f : (0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ continuous.

Define $A$ as $$A=\{ x \in \mathbb R \mid \exists \{ x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty \subset (0,1] \mathrm{\ s.t.}  \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=0, \lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=x \}.$$

Then, prove that $A$ is closed.

It's sufficient to show $A \supset \overline A.$

Let $a\in \overline A$.

Since $\overline A=\{ a \in \mathbb R \mid \exists \{ a_n \}_{n=1}^\infty \subset A \ s.t.\ \lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=a \ \mathrm{in}\ \mathbb R \},$ there exists $\{a_n \}_{n=1}^\infty \subset A$ s.t. $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=a$ in $\mathbb R.$

Then, for all $n \in \mathbb N,$ $a_n \in A$ i.e., there exists $\{ b_m^{(n)} \}_{m=1}^\infty\subset (0,1]$ s.t. $\lim_{m\to \infty}b_m^{(n)}=0, \lim_{m\to \infty} f(b_m^{(n)})=a_n.$

I have to find $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \subset (0,1]$ that confirms $a\in A.$

$\{ b_m^{(n)} \}_{m=1}^\infty\subset (0,1]$ seems to be useful but this is defined for each $n$, so I cannot let simply $x_k=b_k^{(n)}$.

How should I define  $\{ x_k \}_{k=1}^\infty $ ?

Comment: I have not read your proof attempt. My first thought would be to try to show that if $x,y\in A,$ then $[x,y]\subset A,$ so that $A$ is some sort of interval. Then, all you have to check is the endpoints of this interval are in $A$, which shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Not as complicated as you think if you avoid too many sequences:  If $x  \in \overline A$  and $n$ an integer then there is a  $x'\in A $ with  $|x-x'| < \frac{1}{2n}$.    Hence, since $x'\in A$,  there is at least one point  $0< t< \frac{1}{n}$  so that  $|f(t)-x'| <  \frac{1}{2n}$.  Call it $t_n$. 
This means  $|f(t_n)-x| \leq  |f(t_n)-x'| + |x'-x| < \frac{1}{n}$.  So $t_n\to 0$ and $f(t_n)\to x$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Right.  With the (unnecessary) assumption about continuity it is more appropriate to prove that $A$ is a closed interval, rather than merely closed.

Comment: Bonus question (if this was amusing):  *Suppose, moreover, that $A$ is not bounded above.  Prove that there must exist a sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $x_n\to 0$ and $f(x_n)\to\infty$.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Your actual sequence should consist of the $b_m^{(n)}$ values, you just have to pick them correctly. What you can do is this. First, pick some $\epsilon$.

- Look at the sequence $\{b_m^{(1)}\}_{m=1}^\infty$. You know that its limit is $0$, and the limit of $f(b_m^{(1)})$ is $a$. So, you can choose some $m_1$ such that $b_{m_1}^{(1)} < \frac12$ and $|f(b_{m_1}^{(1)}) - a| < \frac12$
- Look at the sequence $\{b_m^{(2)}\}_{m=1}^\infty$. You know that its limit is $0$, and the limit of $f(b_m^{(2)})$ is $a$. So, you can choose some $m_2$ such that $b_{m_2}^{(2)} < \frac14$ and $|f(b_{m_2}^{(2)}) - a| < \frac14$

can you continue from here?

Comment: For each $n$, there exists $m_n$ s.t. $0<b_{m_n}^{(n)}<\frac{1}{2^n}, |f(b_{m_n}^{(n)})-a|<\frac{1}{2^n}$. Let $x_n:=b_{m_n}^{(n)}$. Then $\{x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ works. Is this corect ? @5xum

Comment: @L-20 Exactly that, yes!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some *context* would be interesting for those browsing through here.

Take an arbitrary function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$.  [Yes, forget about continuity which was a silly assumption in the stated problem.]

Define $C^+(f,x)$ to be the set of all numbers $-\infty\leq r\leq +\infty$ for which there is at least one strictly decreasing sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $x$ with $f(x_n)\to r$.  Similarly  $C^-(f,x)$ to be the set of all numbers $-\infty\leq r\leq +\infty$ for which there is at least one strictly *increasing* sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $x$ with $f(x_n)\to r$.

These are called (often) right and left cluster sets for $f$ at the point $x$ although some might call them limit points.

**In any case the sets $C^+(f,x)$  and $C^-(f,x)$  are *always* closed.**

If you must add in the condition that $f$ is continuous except at $x$ then at least add in that, in that case, these sets are closed intervals, not merely closed.

For some entertaining history (I hope it is entertaining) I quote from reference [1] below about the research of the Young family in the UK during the early decades of the 20th century.

> In [W 1908i] is given the following theorem: if $f$ is an arbitrary
> function of a real variable then for all values of $x$, excepting
> perhaps for a countable set, $$\limsup_{h\to 0+} f(x + h) =
>   \limsup_{h\to 0+} f(x - h) \text{  and  } \liminf_{h\to 0+} f(x + h) =
>   \liminf_{h\to 0+} f(x - h).$$   Because the theorem was announced at
> the meeting of the British Association at Leicester in 1907 they used
> to refer to this as the "Leicester theorem." The next year at the Rome
> congress of 1908 this was improved to the statement that again for all
> values of $x$, excepting perhaps for a countable set all of the left and
> right limit numbers are identical. Stated in more modern language this
> theorem (naturally called the "Rome theorem") asserts that at all but
> countably many points the right and left cluster sets of an arbitrary
> function $f$ are identical: for an arbitrary real function $f$,
> $$ C^-(f,x) = C^+(f,x)$$ except at countably many points $x$.
>
> They went on to show in [W 1907ii] that the value $f(x)$ lies in the
> cluster sets, excepting again for countably many points, i.e. $f(x)\in
>   C^+(f,x) = C^-(f,x)$. Similar themes, including analogous results for
> functions of several variables, reappear in the later papers [W
> 1910iii], [WG 1918i] and [W 1928iv] which is one of their last papers.
> (The exceptional set in the several variable case will no longer be
> countable.) They had no small measure of (justified) pride in these
> theorems; for one thing they are genuinely interesting theorems that
> make an assertion true for a completely arbitrary function and they
> are perhaps the first such assertions. This also started a research
> program of searching for "asymmetry" results, i.e. results about the
> distinction between left and right as regards limits and derivatives.
> It is this line of research that culminated in the Denjoy-Young-Saks
> theorem and that has since generated dozens of related inquiries.

**REFERENCES:**

[1] http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/BT-YoungsArticle.pdf

[2] See also Dave Renfro's answer to a similar problem posted in this forum:
[Cluster point of a function at a point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131738/cluster-point-of-a-function-at-a-point)