# Intuitionistic response to Russel's Paradox

Tags: philosophy, paradoxes

I'm having a look at intuitionistic approach to mathematics, and stumbled upon a derivation of Russell's Paradox that doesn't use the LEM. ([Why did mathematicians take Russell's paradox seriously?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24507/why-did-mathematicians-take-russells-paradox-seriously/25038#25038)) What was the Intuitionistic response to this? How did they overcome Russell's paradox? Cheers!

Comment: For [Intuitionistic Set Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/); but - as you said - Russell's Paradox does not need LEM; thus also Intuitionsitic ST msut in some way "restrict" the comprehension principle. See the detail into the Supplement [Axioms of CZF and IZF](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/axioms-CZF-IZF.html); as you can see, there is *Separation*.

Comment: [Intuistionsitic ST](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/) adopts [Intuitionsitic Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/); thus, as a rule of thumb, it must avoid all [Set-theoretic principles incompatible with intuitionistic logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/incompatible-set-axs.html).