# Why is Russell's paradox a paradox and not an illegal definition?

Tags: set-theory

If we define the set of all sets to be $A$,

Then why can't I say that the set $R=\{G \in A | G \notin G\}$
is not well defined?

If it was well defined then $R\in A$ and the condition $G\notin G$ must be well defined if we substitute $G=R$

but it isn't well defined because "Russell's paradox"

so you can change the condition to be
$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      true\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ G=R\\
      G\notin G\ \  \ \ G\neq R
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$
and then it will be well defined

Where is my misunderstanding?

btw, the same idea can be included if you try to disproof the existing of the sets of all sets with Cantor's theorem. If you use the [Wikipedia's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem#Proof) then we can choose $f=Id$ then B is exactly $\{G \in A | G \notin G\}$ and its not well defined as i said before.

**Edit:**

Lot of peoples referencing [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24507/why-did-mathematicians-take-russells-paradox-seriously) but this question is about "why we care about Russell's paradox", but my question is about "Russell's paradox is not a paradox"

I got the answer to the question: Russell's paradox apply on the standard way we define sets-a condition that all element must met to be part of the set. but I thought about sets in more specific way-an infinite/finite nesting of sets.

for example, the set $\{X|X\in X\land\emptyset\in X\land|X|=2\}$ is like {{},{{},{...}}}

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162/why-is-the-set-of-all-sets-a-paradox-in-laymans-terms/909772#909772) shows a good explanation.

Comment: If you downvoted, please tell me what is the issue with the question, and i will fix it. or remove it if its not related to the site.

Comment: I think these [questions and answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24507/why-did-mathematicians-take-russells-paradox-seriously?rq=1) will explain it.

Comment: In naive set theory there is nothing preventing you from forming the set $R$. Russel's paradox shows precisely that you cannot make naive set theory work without paradoxes, so that you do need to make some restrictions on how you form sets so that such paradoxes and similar ones cannot occur. In naive set theory, there is no restriction on how you form sets, and the set you wrote is defined, it just leads to a paradox, which once again, is what made mathematicians develop more rigorous versions of set theory. I'm not sure what you mean about changing the condition.

Comment: @NikolajPedersen i didn't asked what is the implications of Russel's paradox, i asked why can't we just say that Russel's set is an illegal set and the set of all sets is a legal set.

Comment: @Snaw thanks for the answer, i guess that my approach was different, i can define the set of all sets to be any unlimited nesting of infinite sets. and every set is a nesting of limited/unlimited sets. so the standard approach is that a set is a condition that must be met for the element to be in a group.

Comment: @Snaw by changing the condition i mean the right part of the definition of R $R=\{...|change\ this\}$

Comment: The problem is that you really want to be able to have an axiom schema such as Comprehension.  It is, to say the least, not obvious how you would alter that schema to avoid encountering Russell's Paradox while still retaining the structures you do want.

Comment: @RobertShore as i said here in the comments, probably my approach was different, i thought about sets as a limited/unlimited nesting of sets. something like A={{},A} is the same as {{},{{},{...}}} and set of all sets is the set of all possible limited/unlimited nesting of sets. and Russel's set can't be shown as a nesting of sets.

Comment: [See my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162/why-is-the-set-of-all-sets-a-paradox-in-laymans-terms/909772#909772).

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks, that's really help me understand the point.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I already saw this question before I asked this question. and also Nikolaj Pedersen already sent a link to this question. (second comment)

Comment: I understand set theory at an intuitive level only, and in my mind, the resolution to Russell’s paradox is “there’s no such set”. I think the paradox reveals something we must be careful about when developing set theory formally, or axiomatically.

Comment: Te technical term is "set", not *group* (which has a different technical algebraic meaning).